# How do I get to the coordinates (e,1/e) in this question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is my working out i know x/x equals to one but from here I don't know how to get the coordinates. I have been stuck on this since yesterday.[image]

This is the question 8.

The equation of a curve is y=lnx/x. Find the exact coordinates of the stationary point on this curve and determined whether it is a maximum or minimum point.

Comment: Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @saulspatz Okay, I will do that know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, $ y = \frac{\ln x}{x} $ 
For finding stationary points, you need to put $ \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 $ 
$$ \because \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x/x - \ln x}{x^2} $$
We have, $  \frac{x/x - \ln x}{x^2} = 0 \implies  1 - \ln x = 0 \implies x = e $ 
Hence, Stationary point is $ x = e $ where $ y = \frac{1}{e} $

For finding maxima/minima you need to check the sign of $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} $. 
If it’s a positive, then it’s a minima and if it’s negative, then it’s a maxima.

Here, you can find $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} $ to be negative. That means $ (e, \frac{1}{e}) $ is a maxima.

Comment: Yess i get it thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

### HINT

You have already written that stationary points occur when the first derivative is equal to zero. Equate you final expression to zero and multiply both sides by $x^2$. (You will obtain a famous constant as the x-intercept of your stationary point.)

Comment: I got 1-lnx=x^2 what do i do with this?

Comment: $0 \cdot x^2=0$ not $x^2$ on the RHS.

Comment: Yess i see i got it .Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost done.
Your last expression is

$\frac{dy}{dy} = \frac{1 - \ln(x)}{x^2} = 0$

Since RHS is $0$, numerator of LHS must be zero

$1 - \ln(x) = 0$
$\ln(x) = 1$
$x = e^1$.

Thus, $x = e$.
$y = \frac{\ln(x)}{x} = \frac{1}{e}$

Thus the fixed point is $(e, \frac{1}{e})$

Comment: Thank you! but do you also know how to get its nature?

Comment: It's been forever since I worked in derivatives. If I remember correctly, you need to differentiate the last expression again, to get the second order derivative, them plug in values for x(= e). Here my memory runs thin. Based on the sign of this, you can determine whether this is a Maxima or a minima

Answer (score 1):

1. A small point on writing derivatives: when you are calculating derivatives with respect to $x$ , you should write $\frac{d}{dx}(expression)$ . For example, the correct form of the derivative of your problem is:
   $$\frac{x (\frac{d}{dx}\ln x) \;- \; (\ln x) \frac{d}{dx}x}{x^2} $$
2. To find whether the stationary point that you found is a maximum or a minimum, you can calculate the second derivative, then see its sign at the stationary point. A positive *second* derivative means that the *first* derivative is increasing, which means that if the first derivative is now zero, it was negative before, and it will be positive after this point. Now, keeping in mind that the first derivative is the slope of the curve, imagine what this looks like: a curve with negative slope (going down) reaches a stationary point and then its slope becomes positive (going up). This is a minimum. Similarly, you can see that a stationary point where the second derivative is negative, is a maximum. Draw a shape for yourself, it always helps!